# Leray spectral sequence degenerate Case Hartshorne exercise III.8.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

In Hartshorne III.8.1 has the following exercise:

8.1. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map of topological spaces. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$, and assume that $R^i f_*(\mathscr{F})=0$ for all $i>0$. Show that there are natural isomorphisms, for each $i \geqslant 0$,
$$
H^i(X, \mathscr{F}) \cong H^i\left(Y, f_* \mathscr{F}\right) \text {. }
$$

---

The proof can use injective resolution $\mathscr{F}\to \mathscr{J}^\bullet$ and since $R^i f_*(\mathscr{F}) = 0$ for $i>0$ we get also $f_* \mathscr{F}\to f_* \mathscr{J}^\bullet$ being the injective resolution, therefore finish the proof.

Now I want to prove it directly using the $E_2$ degeneration of Leray spectral sequence, since $$E^{i,0}_2 = H^i(Y,f_*\mathscr{F}) \cong \text{Fil}^i(H^i(X,\mathscr{F}))/\text{Fil}^{i+1}(H^i(X,\mathscr{F}))$$due to the convergence of $E_2^{p,q}\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,\mathscr{F})$ where $$H^k(X,\mathscr{F}) = \text{Fil}^0H^k(X,\mathscr{F})\supset ...\supset \text{Fil}^k H^k(X,\mathscr{F})$$
be the decreasing filtration associated to the Leray spectral sequence.

However I found that $$\text{Fil}^i(H^i(X,\mathscr{F}))/\text{Fil}^{i+1}(H^i(X,\mathscr{F})) = \text{Fil}^i H^{i}(X,\mathscr{F})$$is not $H^i(X,\mathscr{F})$, where goes wrong with my proof?

Comment: Ok I see since $E^{p-i,i} = 0$ if $i>0$ by the $R^q f_* \mathscr{F} =0$ which implies that $\text{Fil}^{p-i}H^p/\text{Fil}^{p-i+1} H^p= 0$ which shows $\text{Fil}^0 H^i(X,\mathscr{F}) = \text{Fil}^iH^i(X,\mathscr{F})$.